# Westell 7500 - unable to reach static IPs from external network

Tags: ping, static-ip, modem

I am trying to troubleshoot a network configuration at a remote site. It's a standard configuration for us, that we use across multiple sites. The only difference here is that this ISP uses PPPoE, whereas our others do not.

We were assigned a block of static addresses, using a default gateway from within that block. We are using a Westell 7500 modem, and currently have two machines attached to it that I am trying to reach via Internet through IPMI. The remote techs configured the IPMI settings, using two static IPs from within our block, and the supplied default gateway and subnet.

They sent me the router configuration, and I find it a little confusing. Our WAN IP is the gateway address, which I believe is the right way to configure it, but our WAN gateway is an address we have no knowledge of (our statics start with 209, this WAN gateway address starts with 69). Tech support told us that's fine but didn't really give an explanation of what that should be set at.

I can ping the gateway but not the internal statics (they time out). When the modem is power-cycled all three addresses throw "destination net unreachable."

I don't ever do router configurations; my setup is always everything behind the modem/router. I'd appreciate advice on what to look at and how to try to troubleshoot this.

EDIT: Another tech recommended that we connect a laptop directly to the modem, configure it to one of the static IPs, and see what we get. That computer is able to get Internet access; however, they then turned off Windows Firewall and I was unable to ping them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out that this particular model has a quirk. Turning off the internal firewall does not work all the time. You have to create exceptions to be sure.